# How do I convert an Integer? to an Integer in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net

I'm a C# programmer but am converting some code from C# to VB.NET. In c# I can simply use `(int)blah.getValue()` where `getValue()` returns an `Integer?`

Doing a `DirectCast()` in VB.NET doesn't work though, saying `Integer?` cannot be converted to `Integer`.

Ideas?

Comment: Why would you need to cast it?  If `getValue()` returns `Integer?`, then the `.Value` property is of type Integer.  Just use `blah.getValue().Value`.  Or also use `blah.getValue().GetValueOrDefault(<default value here>)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Integer? is a nullable type, so you may have to convert it to a nullable Integer.

You want to use CType function like so, 'Integer' or 'Integer?' Depending on your situation

```
Val = CType(Source,Integer?)
```

Comment: CType sorted it with just Integer. Thanks!

Comment: -1 This answer is not totally correct. There's a different behaviour for null. `(int) blah.getValue()` throws an exception if `blah.getValue()` is null. `CType(blah.getValue(), Integer)` returns zero if `blah.getValue()` is null.

Answer (score 11):

Use the value property to get the actual integer value.

```
Dim intNullable As Integer?

If intNullable.HasValue Then
 Return intNullable.Value
End If
```

Comment: +1. For bonus marks, add an Else clause that throws `InvalidOperationException "Nullable object must have a value."` That's what happens when the C# `(int)` cast encounters a `null` value.

Comment: This is the correct answer. (An Else clause is superfluous when you test '.HasValue')

Answer (score 1):

```
myNonNullableVar = if(myNullableVar, 0)
```

will set 0 if integer? is null or return the actual value.

In [C#](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_%28programming_language%29), it would be:

```
 myNonNullableVar = myNullableVar ?? 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

CInt(ValueToBeInteger)

Answer (score 1):

If you use CType or CInt or another conversion function to convert the nullable integer to a regular integer, a null value will be converted to zero.

Check to see if the nullable type has a value as in @Rhapsody 's answer.

You can also use the nullable type methods `.GetValueOrDefault()` and `.GetValueOrDefault(x)`. The overload without any parameters returns the default value of the datatype if the value is null. E.g. Integer default value is zero; Boolean default value is False. The overload with a parameter allows you to specify a default value to use if the value is null.

[Nullable.GetValueOrDefault Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72cec0e0.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You should use [CType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4x2877xb%28VS.80%29.aspx) function like this:

```
CType(blah.getValue(), Integer)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dim a as integer? = 1
dim b as integer = a.value
```

Remember to check if a.hasvalue (returns boolean, true if a has value).

Answer (score -1):

@SLC: It is very simple to get values of Nullable Int32? of C# into Integer.

Example:

```
    ID(Nullable<Int32?>)
```

You have to do:
**ID.value**

where ID is a NullableObject.

And it will return an integer in VB.NET.

Comment: The language sample provided looks like it's in C# and the OP was specifically asking for VB.NET.  I'm not sure this answer provides any additional information to the wealth of answers already available on this question.

Comment: `Nullable<Int32?>` makes no sense.  Perhaps you meant to type `Nullable<Int32>` (without the question mark)?